# Errors during changing collations of all columns of all tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to change collation for all columns of all tables in MySQL. I saw in other posts that it can be as following

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_NAME, '` MODIFY COLUMN `', COLUMN_NAME,'` ',
              DATA_TYPE, IF(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL
       OR DATA_TYPE LIKE 'longtext', '', CONCAT('(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
                                         ')')
       ), ' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;') AS 'USE whitesource_collate_test;'
    FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_schema'
           AND (SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_TYPE
                FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA =
                       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEMA
                       AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME =
                           INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
                LIMIT  1) LIKE 'BASE TABLE'
           AND DATA_TYPE IN ( 'char', 'varchar' )
```

After creating and running the script on part of tables I am getting errors like

```
Referencing column 'COL1_ID_' and referenced column 'ID_' in foreign key constraint 'MY_FK_GROUP' are incompatible
```

As I understand this can cause because of order of tables processed. The question is - what is the best way to handle such errors except of manually process tables with errors ? Thanks in advance

Comment: deny access to db >>set foreign_key_checks = 0  >> do stuff >> set foreign_key_checks = 1 ,test in test before production..

Comment: As @P.Salmon Disable foreign key check then proceed